# Why am i getting Set[Char] instead of Set[String]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, key-value

I am trying to create a key value pair from a text input, where key will be String and value will be `Set[String]`. But I think I get `Set[Char]`.
My code is:

```
val newRdd = textFile.map(x => (x.split("\t")(1), x.split("\t")(2).toSet)).reduceByKey(_++_)
```

What I want is pairs like:

> (title1, Set(m1))

but instead i get:

> (title1, Set(m,1))

The input is something like this:

```
1  title1  m1
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: TextFile variable basically is a sequence of strings right ?

Comment: @zenwraight Give or take. For the purpose of this question you can assume API similar to any `Seq[String]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `String` is essentially `Seq[Char]` and [`toSet` is](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#toSet[B%3E:A]:scala.collection.immutable.Set[B]):

```
def toSet[B >: Char]: Set[B]
```

You probably wanted:

```
map(x => (x.split("\t")(1), Set(x.split("\t")(2)))
```